# How to train or calibrate stream flow accumulation using observation data?

Tags: raster-calculator, watershed, flow-accumulation, stream-order

I need to calculate flowrate at designated coordinates (Point of interest - POI) in a watershed. I have real-world data from stream gauge stations along this watershed for each 50-150 km2 rainfall area but these measurement locations are off the path or too far away from POI. I want to calibrate/train the flow accumulation values according to these data so that I can calculate flow at my POI.

Is there any tool for this. I am using Hydrosheds rasters for flow accumulation/direction calculations, and QGIS but have access to ArcGIS too.

Comment: Read on 'estimation of runoff at ungauged locations'. You'll see that this is much greater task than you think. This is good example when power of all computer's in the world, cloud computing, ai etc are not much help.

Comment: @FelixIP thank you for your remark. I see that 'estimation of runoff at ungauged locations' is a complicated task. Since I am trying to reproduce gauged watershed, a tool such as SWAT might be used however it might be an overkill for what I want to achieve.  I am trying to get approximate numbers without building a complex hydrological model.

Comment: Try regression analysis between known Q and flow accumulation (catchment area).